# Define relationship type in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

Hello I'd like to set a relationship between two `messages` by adding an additional relationship type.

Example:

```
message2 isDuplicate message3  
message3 isSuccessor message4
message4 isPredecessor message3
etc.
```

The number of types is not fixed so adding an relationship for each type is not a real option. I SQL would do something like:

```
Message{_id_, text}
msgRelation{_msgID1_, _msgID2_, type} 
//_msgID1_, _msgID2_ foreign keys to Message.id
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to add an entity to model the relationship itself.

```
RelateType{
  type:string // ...isDuplicate, isSuccessor, isPredecessor etc
  fromMessage<<-->Message.toMessages
  toMessage<<-->Message.fromMessages
}

Message{
  title:string
  toMessages<-->>RelateType.fromMessages
  fromMessages<-->>RelateType.toMessages
}
```

The `RelateType` will form a bridge between any two `Messages`. The `RelateType.type` relationship will let you model any arbitrary kind of relationship. To find any particular `Message` objects relationships by type you just:

```
NSString *relateType=@"isDuplicate";
NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type == %@", relateType];
NSSet *duplicateMsgs=[msgObj filteredSetUsingPredicate:p];
```

Alternatively, you can do a fetch on the `RelateType` entity to find all of a certain type of relationship e.g. all `isDuplicate` relationships.

However, usually if you find yourself doing something like this, it's because you've tried to shoehorn a SQL schema into Core Data model which is always a mistake.